# What does 'echo 0 > foo' mean?

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to know what does this code mean?

```
echo 0 > foo
```

Completely new to Unix and Bash commands. Lots of stuff to learn, but need a quick answer to this question.

Comment: The answer below is correct. Here is a link for additional reading on this topic: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Now that you have accepted an answer, your question will be marked as solved. You don't need to edit the title.

Comment: You can use `man echo` or google to find what commands do. For syntax like `>`, you can search `man bash` or use the "name syntax" feature on [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It echoes `0` to a file named `foo`. In other words, it redirects the output, 0, to a file named "foo", instead of showing it on the screen.

From a basic [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) example on redirection:

> `command1 > file1`
>
> executes command1, placing the output in file1, as opposed to
>   displaying it at the terminal, which is the usual destination for
>   standard output.

Comment: Just to make it a little clearer for someone new to shell scripting: Here, 'echo' means 'print'.

Answer (score 3):

The command `echo 0 > foo` overwrites whatever content is in the file `foo` - or creates it if it doesn't exist - and replaces it with `0`.

The command `echo 0 >> foo` will add `0` to the end of the file `foo`, or create a file containing `0` if it doesn't exist.